# What is the worst case time complexity of Java 14+ Arrays.sort( int[] )?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, quicksort, java-14

While I know this seems obvious I'll explain my confusion. I've always thought of Quicksort's worst case time complexity as O(n^2). The documentation for [Arrays.sort(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) from Java 7 to Java 13 says:
*This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on **many** data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.*

The keyword here is "many", so I assume O(n log(n)) here refers to the average case, and there still exists data sets that result in a worst case of O(n^2).

But in Java 14 and up, the documentation for [Arrays.sort(int[])](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)) says:
*This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on **all** data sets*.

So is the worst case for this improved implementation of Quicksort now O(n log(n)) ? Someone please clarify.

Comment: maybe they not using quickSort now? there are few sort algorithms that are quicker than quickSort https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexities-of-all-sorting-algorithms/

Comment: I'm not sure about Java 14 but in 17 in doc about Arrays.sort there is written that it's using Dual-Pivot quicksort which is faster than one pivot quick sort. quote from doc "The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on all data sets, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations."

Comment: @Szprota21 Both versions of the docs I linked say, *The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch.* And yes I believe 14-17 are identical. My question is the same.

Comment: You need to go deeper. Into DualPivotQuicksort.sort(a, 0, 0, a.length);
You will see that it has different implementation from java 7 to 13 when if complexity becomes close to n^2 it will switch to quicksort but quicksort have worst complexity of n^2 and from java 14 it switches to heapsort which have complexity of nlogn

Comment: @Szprota21 Holy cow you're right I just found this: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java

There's a comment that says, "Switch to heap sort if execution time is becoming quadratic."

Thank you for clearing this up, I've been scratching my head about this for a while. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check deeper implementation of  Arrays.sort(int[]).

Inside there is a function DualPivotQuicksort.sort(...) which is used for sorting.

You can see in java 7 to 13 that function have a fail safe mechanism which changes sorting type if complexity is near O(n^2), it's changing to QuickSort which average complexity is O(n log n) but it's worst is O(n^2) that's why in javaDoc description says "many data sets".

On the other hand since java 14 fail safe for higher complexity is changing sort algorithm to heapsort which have worst complexity of O(n log n) so it never will be slower than that.